# How to omit numbering in the last page of every chapter

Tags: numbering, chapters, context, footer

I am writing a fiction work with ConTeXt.

Every chapter and my four parts pages begin with their corresponding odd page.
I have no problem with every last chapter page containing the text: whether was an odd or an even page, they do not have their related numbering in the footer, and the blank odd last pages have empty header too.

[image]

So far, that performance is **almost** what I need, and what I get thanks to Aditya's and Wolfgang's help. I know that this requirement may appear a very particular option, but it is a common practice among most of the fiction Spanish writings, and it is a must for me too.

Why I wrote **almost**? Because of the same error: unfortunately, there is always an exception in my last chapter, every time.

[image]

As I said, I have been messing around with my setup thanks to the guys here.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided, 
   location=] 

\setupheadertexts
[][{\switchtobodyfont[head]\tfz\em\getmarking[part]}][{\switchtobodyfont[head]\tfz\em\getmarking[chapter]}][]
\setupfootertexts[][pagenumber]

\definepagebreak [ebohoyod] [footer,yes,header,footer,right]

%\unprotect
%\installpagebreakmethod {ebohoyod}
%  {\page_otr_command_flush_all_floats
%   \doifoddpageelse
%      {\page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts
%       \setupheader[state=empty]%
%       \setupfooter[state=empty]%
%       \page_reset_marks_and_insert_dummy}
%      {\setupfooter[state=empty]%
%       \page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts}}
%\protect

\setuphead[chapter][page=ebohoyod,number=no,alternative=middle,
header=empty,style=tfb,
before={\blank[force,34pt]},
after={\blank[114pt]}]

\setuphead[part][page=ebohoyod,placehead=yes,number=no,
alternative=middle,header=empty,footer=empty, style=tfd,
before={\blank[force,154pt]}\hskip 4pt]
```

Because of my ignorance, I tried several combinations. For example, if I comment out the `\unprotect` code, the performance is good in the even pages, but it fails in the all the odd pages.

Speaking of my lack of resources, I do not know if my short body text setup may be of aid. I record my frontmatter files and my chapters as \input, but I have set up my part pages directly. I can see here any interference with my preamble setup, but, just in case.

```
\starttext

\startfrontmatter
    \input /frontmatter/cover-verso.tex
    \input /frontmatter/tit-auth-edit.tex
    \input /frontmatter/epigraph.tex
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
\startpart
[title={C\switchtobodyfont[indpart]uentos grises}]
\setlayer
      [yinyang]
      [x=106pt,y=200pt]
      {\externalfigure[GloucesterCathedral][width]}
    \input /bodymatter/relato1.tex
    \input /bodymatter/relato2.tex
\stoppart

\startpart
[title={C\switchtobodyfont[indpart]uentos verdes}]
\setlayer
      [yinyang]
      [x=106pt,y=200pt]
      {\externalfigure[GloucesterCathedral][width]}
    \input /bodymatter/relato3.tex
    \input /bodymatter/relato4.tex
\stoppart

\startpart
[title={C\switchtobodyfont[indpart]uentos azules}]
\setlayer
      [yinyang]
      [x=106pt,y=200pt]
      {\externalfigure[GloucesterCathedral][width]}
    \input /bodymatter/relato5.tex
    \input /bodymatter/relato6.tex  
\stoppart

\startpart
[title={C\switchtobodyfont[indpart]uentos rojos}]
\setlayer
      [yinyang]
      [x=106pt,y=200pt]
      {\externalfigure[GloucesterCathedral][width]}
    \input /bodymatter/relato7.tex
    \input /bodymatter/relato8.tex
\stoppart
\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
\startstandardmakeup[doublesided=yes]
\setupinterlinespace[line=18pt]
\completecontent[criterium=all]
\blank[280pt]
\stopstandardmakeup 
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's a reasonable question. It would be easier for us to experiment if you edited your question and added a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that compiles and demonstrates your problem. In particular, the document class that you are using is almost certainly relevant.

Comment: Document class with ConTeXt? I do not understand you. But I will post my code.

Comment: "A must" in fiction writings? I have not read fiction novels for centuries, but I have just check a few that I have still unread at home and it seems that still some people that do not take care of this. Besides, I personally doubt that this could be of some benefit  for the reader.

Comment: You are right, Fran. There is no practical reason for that in the majority of Spanish publications. But it is a fact.
Maybe, my sin is to be very purist with these semi-standards.

Comment: Is the `Ceuntos Verdes` page a new `part`? If so, you'd have to add `\setuphead[part][page=...]` similar to the setup for `chapter`.

Comment: Ah! I see. Ufff... You are right. I can not understand the central part of your code, but it is obvious, even for me, what you have pointed out here. When I arrived home, sooner rather than later, I will try it.

Comment: @Aditya As you said, \setuphead[part] is necessary. The problem is **almost** solved now. But, as I wrote below, I must update my question.

Comment: @Aditya I have updated my question. As you can see, my sample code is more minimal now.

Comment: By "last chapter" do you mean the last chapter of frontmatter and bodymatter etc?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, exactly. You have been precise: the "last chapter" is the last file among all the \input ones you can see within my second sample code.

Comment: Then Wolfgang's suggestion to add the `page` option to `setupsectionblock` will work

Comment: @Aditya You have hit the nail on the head. Now it works perfectly. Solved.

Comment: @Aditya Now I have a dilemma. You two have been very helpful to me. I pressed yours both accept symbols. However, they are selective.
I understand the philosophy behind that, but it is upset for me.
What would be the fairest clicking?

Comment: @ebohoyod: Don't worry too much about it. The 'tick mark' only gives us fake internet currency :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Settings for the page break

Use the order of the keywords for the `page` (or as argument for the `\definepagebreak` command) of the `\setuphead` command.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,
   location={footer,right}]

% \setuphead
%   [chapter]
%   [page={footer,yes,header,footer,right}]

\definepagebreak [chapter] [footer,yes,header,footer,right]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [page=chapter]

\setupheadertexts [] [chapter]

\starttext

\chapter{Knuth}

\dorecurse{10}{\samplefile{knuth}}

\chapter{Zapf}

\dorecurse{10}{\samplefile{zapf}}

\chapter{Ward}

\dorecurse{5}{\samplefile{ward}}

\stoptext
```

[image: Page 2 and 3]

[image: Page 4 and 5]

[image: Page 6 and 7]

## Extended example for the whole document

The following example includes also the settings which you have to apply to get the correct results when you add `\part` headers and `sectionblocks` which add additional page break.

Especially the `sectionblock` settings are necessary because the finish the chapters before the next `\part` can use the correct settings for the page break.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,
   location=none]

\setupheader
  [style={\switchtobodyfont[10pt]\it}]

\setupheadertexts
  [] [part]
  [chapter] []

\setupfootertexts
  [] [pagenumber]

\definepagebreak [ebohoyod] [footer,yes,header,footer,right]

\setuphead
  [part]
  [page=ebohoyod,
   placehead=yes,
   number=no,
   alternative=middle,
   header=empty,
   footer=empty]

\setuphead
  [title,chapter]
  [page=ebohoyod,
   number=no,
   alternative=middle,
   header=empty]

\setupsectionblock
  [page=ebohoyod]

\setuppapersize [A5] [A5]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

    \startstandardmakeup [align=middle,pagestate=start]

    {\tfd Sample document}

    \stopstandardmakeup

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

    \startpart [title={First part}]

        \startchapter [title={Chapter One}]
        \dorecurse{4}{\samplefile{douglas}}
        \stopchapter

        \startchapter [title={Chapter Two}]
        \dorecurse{4}{\samplefile{waltham}}
        \stopchapter

    \stoppart

    \startpart [title={Second part}]

        \startchapter [title={Chapter Three}]
        \dorecurse{4}{\samplefile{dawkins}}
        \stopchapter

        \startchapter [title={Chapter Four}]
        \dorecurse{4}{\samplefile{carey}}
        \stopchapter

    \stoppart

\stopbodymatter

\startappendices

    \completecontent

\stopappendices

\stoptext
```

Comment: Yes, Wolfgang, your result is what I am seeking. But I still see nothing wrong in my above-transcribed code. It is frustrating.
Nevertheless, I will post another graphic example with the "good news" and the "bad news" mentioned above to Aditya.
I sense I am missing a very, very little detail.

Comment: My issue is almost solved, but not yet. Would you mind doing me the favour of reviewing my update?

Answer (score 3):

> Furthermore, I put at the end of all whatever.tex chapters the \page[empty] command before \stopchapter. Why? Because I want the last even page without headers and footers when these pages does not have text.
>
> Of course, when the last even page does have text, I comment the \page[empty] command in the pertinent chapter.

The right way to do this is to define a page break that removes the headers and footers:

```
\definepagebreak[chapterbreak]
                [yes,header,footer,right]

\setuphead[chapter][page=chapterbreak]
```

However, this does not address your second question. For that, I define a new page break that checks if one is on an odd or an even page and disables the header and footer accordingly.

```
\unprotect
\installpagebreakmethod {ebohoyod}
  {\page_otr_command_flush_all_floats
   \doifoddpageelse
      {\page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts
       \setupheader[state=empty]%
       \setupfooter[state=empty]%
       \page_reset_marks_and_insert_dummy}
      {\setupfooter[state=empty]%
       \page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts}}
  \protect

\setuphead[chapter][page=ebohoyod]
```

Here is a complete example. Note that I had used `\setupfootertexts` to add page numbers in the footer rather than `\setuppagenumbering`.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided, location=]

\setupheadertexts[][part][chapter][]
\setupfootertexts[][pagenumber]

\unprotect
\installpagebreakmethod {ebohoyod}
  {\page_otr_command_flush_all_floats
   \doifoddpageelse
      {\page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts
       \setupheader[state=empty]%
       \setupfooter[state=empty]%
       \page_reset_marks_and_insert_dummy}
      {\setupfooter[state=empty]%
       \page_otr_command_next_page_and_inserts}}
  \protect

\setuphead[part][placehead=yes, number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][page=ebohoyod]

\starttext

\startpart[title=Part one]
\startchapter
    [title=Test chapter]

    Page 1 

\stopchapter

\startchapter
    [title=Test chapter]

    Page 1 \page
    Page 2 

\stopchapter

\startchapter
    [title=Test chapter]

    Page 1 \page
    Page 2 \page
    Page 3 

\stopchapter

\startchapter
    [title=Test chapter]

    Page 1 \page
    Page 2 \page
    Page 3 \page
    Page 4 

\stopchapter
\stoppart
\stoptext
```

Here is a chapter when the previous chapter ended on an odd page:

[image]

and here is a chapter when the previous chapter ended on an even page

[image]

Comment: My bad, Aditya. No more \page[empty], commented or not, at the end of chapters. I recognise it was not the best way. In order to not change my novel's look, I have modified your example, but taking care of your code. The good news: some last pages have no numbering. The bad news: I do not see any constant pattern about the error pages. It seems an apparently random performance, but I know this can not be true: I am missing something here. I have changed my above previous code sample. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Did you change the page numbering to use `\setupfooter` rather than the `location` parameter of `\setuppagenumbering`? You'd have to create a **minimal** example demonstrating the issue. The trouble is that your code is not **minimal**. Try to start removing parts of your setup that are irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: OK, I will update my post.

Comment: I have just arrived home now, and no, I did not change the location parameter of \setuppagenumbering.